# Links in stackexchange.com top bar sometimes shown as two rows instead of one

Tags: bug, top-bar, stackexchange.com, responsive-design

In Firefox and Chrome on my Mac, with some window sizes the 'Tour', 'About Us' and 'Meta' links are displayed in two rows instead of one:

[image]

It's probably browser-dependent, since I can't reproduce it in Safari.

Comment: Repro here on Windows. Brave, up-to-date (chrome equivalent). No repro on chrome however. Damned if I know.

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome (latest version) on Windows 11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/db9Ql.png

Comment: Forgot Win 11 was out, mine was on 10.

Comment: huh. i forgot links up there even existed.

Comment: huh, we have stackexchange.com?

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome on Windows 10 but only when the window is small enough that the search field is replaced with the magnifying glass icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBLLN.png